# VBA Take specific values from one array into another array dynamically

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic

I have an array with over 130 elements, out of those elements I only want specific elements. Those elements I have been able to specify with an if statement and an `Instr` function. However, I am stuck when figuring out how to those values from main array into a different array. The issue is that I don't know how many values will actually fit the requirements and so the second array I can't define before the values are counted.

How would I transfer certain values that fit the `Instr` function from one array to the other array.

Current code -

```
For v = 0 To UBound(NViews)

  ViewNames = NViews(v)
    If InStr(ViewNames, "Triage Folder") Then
    ReDim TriageNames(0 To p)
    TriageNames(p) = NViews(v)
    p = p + 1
  End If

Next
```

Updated Code**

```
p = 1
ReDim TriageNames(0 To p)

For v = 0 To UBound(NViews)

ViewNames = NViews(v)
If InStr(ViewNames, "Triage Folder") Then

TriageNames(p) = NViews(v)
p = p + 1

ReDim Preserve TriageNames(0 To p)

End If

Next
```

Comment: Use `ReDim Preserve` on the second array, after you've populated it.

Comment: @BigBen I did it, it works, I'm not sure why and both the first and the last element are now blank.

Comment: You want to `ReDim Preserve` *after* the loop.

Comment: Oh.. yea, of course..

Comment: A better solution is to use a an ArrayList.  Create the arraylist using create object (e.g. CreateObject("ArrayList")_  Then just use the .add method to add items to the arraylist. W hen you have processed the first array, you can get an array of the arraylist by using its .ToArray method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `TriageNames` the same size as `NViews`, then use `ReDim Preserve`, after you populated `TriageNames` completely:

```
Dim TriageNames As Variant
ReDim TriageNames(0 to Ubound(NViews))

For v = 0 To Ubound(NViews)
   If InStr(NViews(v), "Triage Folder") > 0 Then
       Dim p As Long
       TriageNames(p) = NViews(v)
       p = p + 1
   End If
Next

If p > 0 Then
   ReDim Preserve TriageNames(0 to p - 1)
End If
```